# Improve code readability and speed in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

***[PROBLEM 1]*** I have some VBA commands that make sheet named "MS1" in Excel perform a series of tasks. Some example below:

```
Sheets("MS1").Unprotect Password:="0123" 
Sheets("MS1").Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheets("MS1").OLEObjects("label1").Object.Caption = "this is label 1"
Sheets("MS1").Select
    Range("A1").Value = "Hello"
Sheets("MS1").Protect Password:="0123"
```

**[QUESTION 1]** I would like a more concise code by avoiding the repetition of "Sheets("MS1")", so as to improve readability and processing speed. Please, feel free to demonstrate solutions.

---

***[PROBLEM 2]*** By exploring code readability ...

```
    Option explicit

    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="0123"

    Dim R As Variant
    Dim CONJ3 As Variant

   With Worksheets("MS2")
     .Unprotect Password:="4567"
     .Range("K12").Value = R
     .Protect Password:="4567", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
   End with

     CONJ3 = Array("Jan " & R, "Feb " & R, "Mar " & R, "Apr " & R, _
         "Mai " & R, "Jun " & R, "Jul " & R, "Aug " & R, "Set " & R, _    
         "Oct " & R, "Nov " & R, _"Dec " & R, "MS3", "MS4", "MS5")

   With Worksheets("CONJ3")
     .Unprotect Password:="4567"
     .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
     .Protect Password:="4567", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
   End With
```

**[QUESTION 2]** I have now some issues with run-time error9:subscript out of range (possible array error). How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) serves to provide a single parent worksheet reference that all methods and properties within the With ... End With block can reference with a prefixing period (aka *full stop*).

```
With Worksheets("MS1")
    .Unprotect Password:="0123"
    .Visible = xlSheetVisible
    '.OLEObjects("label1").Object.Caption = "this is label 1"
    With .Range("A1")
        .Value = "Hello"
        .Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End With
    .Protect Password:="0123"
    .Activate   'bring to the foreground
End With
```

This also improves code execution in that the single reference is carried along as opposed to making repeated requests to establish the parent worksheet.

The nested With ... End With statement isolates the next two commands to a single cell. This could be a single cell or a range of cells.

Comment: Great. Thank you @Jeeped!

Comment: YW. I don't really get the down-vote or the VTC. There might be a couple of different ways to improve things but the most obvious to me was the `With ... End With`. Neither *too broad* nor *opinion based* in my estimation.

Comment: I am now having trouble with arrays :) Found out several examples on the internet, adapted them but none worked for my specific needs

Comment: I'll try to keep an eye out for your question.

Answer (score 0):

The code below solved [problem 2]. Now I can modify several aspects at once and only in chosen worksheets:

```
Option explicit

Sub Testing ()

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect Password:="0123"

  Dim R As Variant
  Dim CONJ3 As Worksheet

  With Worksheets("MS2")
    .Unprotect Password:="4567"
    .Range("K12").Value = R
    .Protect Password:="4567", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
  End with

For Each CONJ3 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
      Select Case CONJ3.Name
      Case Is = "Jan " & R, "Feb " & R, "Mar " & R, "Apr " & R, _
         "Mai " & R, "Jun " & R, "Jul " & R, "Aug " & R, "Set " & R, _
         "Oct " & R, "Nov " & R, "Dec " & R, "MS3", "MS4", "MS5"

  With CONJ3
    .Unprotect Password:="4567"
    .Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    .Protect Password:="4567", UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
  End With

  Case Else
  End Select
  Next CONJ3

 ActiveWorkbook.Protect Password:="0123", Structure:=True, Windows:=False

End Sub
```